# Override edmx model generation from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first, entity-framework-6.1

When using EF Database First, it's easy to select tables/sprocs from the database, and have these added to the model.

However I want to customize the way the model is updated from the database, to automatically set certain features, and save user effort/error.

To be clear, I'm not talking about making changes at the point of the tt file generation, but actually when the edmx is populated from the database via the wizard.

The particular actions I'm interested in are:

1. Automatically adding some sprocs to the model when a table is added, based on a strict convention.
2. Setting those sprocs to be `Private` (they are `Public` by default)
3. Automatically mapping those sprocs to the CRUD operations for the table.

It seems that there are a couple of options:

1. Override the default model generation, so that the changes are made when the table is added/updated.
2. Update the XML for the edmx after tables are added (can I trigger this automatically?)

I'd rather do option 1, as it would be far cleaner, but haven't found a mechanism to achieve this yet. (I'm working through the EF code from CodePlex at the moment!)

Am I stuck with option 2?

Comment: I don't see any other option than 2. With code-first, as of EF 6,  it's much easier by the new [MapToStoredProcedures()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237184%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method.